# How do I debug Visual Studio 2010 error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using VS2010, and I am getting an error when I create a new MVC 3 project. The error I get is "The method or operation is not implemented". Now when I start VS2010 in safe mode, I can create a new project without getting this error.

So, how can I figure out what is causing the issue? I tried to uninstall all the extensions that I had in the extension manager but that did not help.

What else is not loaded when in safe mode?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a busted install. Have you tried repairing the installation?

Comment: I'm inclined to think your MVC3 installation is corrupt.  You might want to try reinstalling it.

Comment: I would agree, but I also tried MVC 4 and this gives the same result. But MVC 2 works fine. Also like I said when in "safe mode" everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start VS in safe mode, you're deactivating all 3rd party modules. I'm inclined to **guess** that one of your plugins are causing the issue.

Comment: any tips on how to figure out what is installed?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your VS installation? Any plugins installed?

Comment: Once I uninstalled my version control plugin it now works fine.